# Load DataTemplate from file or string in windowsphone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I´m developing an application from windows phone, and I need that user could configure DataTemplete of DataList.
The application uses WCF to load data from external database, and I think that I can use this method in order to desing a DataContext(following user indications) and sent it to windows phone application, save it on a file an then load this file.

I´m traying this, but I get an error on last line

string dt = @"

```
            <TextBlock 
                Text=""{Binding Codigo}"" 
                FontSize=""{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}""
                Grid.Column=""0"" 
                VerticalAlignment=""Top""/>

            <TextBlock 
                Text=""{Binding Nombre}"" 
                FontSize=""{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"" 
                Grid.Column=""1"" 
                VerticalAlignment=""Top""/>";            

        listLineas.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(dt);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be created a valid XAML DataTemplate in the string?

```
string dt = @"
    <DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">  
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock 
                Text=""{Binding Codigo}"" 
                FontSize=""{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}""
                Grid.Column=""0"" 
                VerticalAlignment=""Top""/>

            <TextBlock 
                Text=""{Binding Nombre}"" 
                FontSize=""{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"" 
                Grid.Column=""1"" 
                VerticalAlignment=""Top""/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>";

    listLineas.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(dt);
```

Note that there has to be a default namespace declared, and that the content can only be set once (hence the wrapping StackPanel)

Comment: This answer addresses the "how", rather than the "why", but since you don't say why you want this I haven't gone into the pros and cons of this approach.